# How to perform a segue according to network connection?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, webkit

I'm new at Xcode platform and iOS programming.

- I want to open webkit view if there's network connection. If there's no connection, I want to open another page.
- I have a segue for second page with an id of "seque1".

But my code didn't work. I don't understand why.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
            print("Internet Connection Available!")
            let url = URL(string: "https://www.URL.com")
            let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
            webview.load(request)
        }else{
            print("Internet Connection not Available!")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "seque1", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you present your ViewController you get the correct print depending on network status?

Comment: try this in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Please make sure that your identifier for segue is correct , here you use `seque1` may be it is `segue1`, please recheck your storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Great question...

You should watch out for these events on `AppDelegate.swift`, so you know, before things get in hands, you choose what should happen

Using `RootViewController`, you decide what to come first, so if the user isn't connected, transfer them to the viewcontroller that says there's no connection, if they do, proceed them.

Paste this code on your `Appdelegate.swift`

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {`
        let No_InternetViewController = NoInternetViewController() // your no internet vc
        let WebkitVC = WebkitVC() // orginial one


        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){

            self.window?.rootViewController = WebkitVC as! WebkitVC

        } else {

            print("Internet Connection not Available!")

            self.window?.rootViewController = No_InternetViewController as! No_InternetViewController
        }
       return true
}
```